# How to add label or sprite over another sprite in cocos2d android?

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-android

```
CCSprite butonSprite=CCSprite.sprite("magnet.png");
    CCLabel label1=CCLabel.makeLabel("START", "Arial", 30);
    label1.setPosition(0,0);
    butonSprite.addChild(label1);

    ccMacros.CCLOG("", ""+butonSprite.getChildren());

    CCMenuItemSprite item=CCMenuItemSprite.item(butonSprite, butonSprite,this,"goToGameScreen");
    CCMenu menu=CCMenu.menu(item);
```

Only the sprite is visible. How to make the label visible? i tried setting position to  label.

Comment: Try initialising the label with a size, and also setting its colour.

Comment: i tried setting color and size, even then the label is not visible:(

Answer (score 0):

Your label may be is beneath the position of the sprite, try to change the z-ordering greater than z-ordering of the sprite

e.g.

[sprite addChild:label z: 10];